# An exact sequence of structure sheaves of closed subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X, Y, Z\subset \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ be three closed subschemes of the same dimension. Assume that for an integer $m>0$ we have an exact sequence

$0\to \mathcal{O}_X\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-m)\to \mathcal{O}_Y\to \mathcal{O}_Z\to 0.$

Is it generally true that $Y=X\cup Z$ as the union of closed subschemes?

My idea is that we can look at the annihilators $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(-)$. But it seems that in general we only have $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_Y)=\mathcal{I}_Y\subset \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(-m))\cap \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_Z)=\mathcal{I}_X\cap \mathcal{I}_Z$.

Can we prove $\mathcal{I}_X\cap \mathcal{I}_Z\subset \mathcal{I}_Y$ in this case? If not, what extra conditions do we need? Is it enough to assume that $Y$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the supports for these sheaves. Since these subschemes are closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$, they should be noetherian. Hence the structure sheaf of each is coherent. In commutative algebra we know that the Supp of a module is additive (not really but a union) with respect to a short exact sequence. I believe that the same holds for coherent sheaves. Here you have
$$\text{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X)=X,\quad \text{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y)=Y,\quad\text{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Z)=Z$$
and
$$\text{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(-m))=\text{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X)\cap\text{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(-m))=X$$

Comment: Thanks! But I think here the $\mathrm{Supp}(-)$ you mentioned is just closed subset, and its scheme structure is given by $\mathcal{O}$ quotient the annihilators.  See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JV  An counter-example of the additivity of scheme-theoric $\mathrm{Supp}(-)$ is given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3707370/relation-between-annihilators-and-exact-sequence